# OpenCV segmentation fault when converting video to PNG sequence

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault

Converting to webm first causes the frame of segmentation fault failure to move to frame 1308, instead of 1301.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void conv_vid_png(string input_path, string output_path){

  VideoCapture cap(input_path);
  int count = 0;
  if(!cap.isOpened()){
       cout << "Error opening video stream or file" << endl;
      }
  while(1) {
    Mat frame;
    //Why the fuck does this use the stream insertion operator?
    // >> appears to both increment and store
    cap >> frame;
    //Break the loop when there are no more frames to capture
    if (frame.empty())
          break;

    imwrite(output_path+"frame"+to_string(count)+".png", frame);
    cout << "frame " + to_string(count) + " processed" << endl; 
    count++;
  }
}

int main()
{
  string in_path = "./movie_type_files/vert_beach_short.mp4";
  string out_path = "./tmp_png/";

  conv_vid_png(in_path, out_path); //First, convert the video file to png sequence
  return 0;
}
```

Which uses the OpenCV VideoCapture object to write each frame of a video to PNGs. I did not have a problem with this same function in OpenCV for python. The segmentation fault happens at the same frame (1301) despite there ostensibly being nothing out of the ordinary about that frame.

Thoughts on a solution?  I'm currently using ffmpeg to convert the .mp4 to a webm to see if the issue persists. This is my first C++ program so I am struggling to self diagnose my problem. I followed a guide on diagnosing segmentation faults and have included the results I gathered below.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looking at the matx header, it seems that one of the frames thinks it has more channels than in reality. Try to print out frame.channels(). You may also try forcing color space conversion with cvtColor(frame,frameConverted,COLOR_BGR2GRAY), I am not sure how fool proof that conversion is, maybe it is a bit more cautious? Anyway, even if it works it will reduce number of channels to 1, but maybe will help to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: I'd suggest swapping imwrite out with *imshow* for testing. look at what data you receive. I concur, check type and size and all that. a segfault is frustrating and I wonder why there isn't more information coming out of the code. I see involvement of `Matx`, which I find odd, since your code doesn't use it, and the APIs you call shouldn't need it either. is **this code** exactly what you execute? the output from GDB implies something more going on... `super_imposer_c`?

Comment: @styku The frame is fine, I printed the number of channels each frame. 
I think this has something to do with threading, and how I handle breaking the loop, since the number of remaining frames to render is less than the number of threads open for the task.
Thoughts?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Its not exact, but the only differences exist in imports and things that happen after the function to then further process the rendered frames.  I reinstalled openCV to the latest version, hoping for an easy fix, but no dice.  Or maybe I did it wrong, since I installed openCV4, but I have to include open CV2.  IDK what im doing bros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The segmentation fault actually happened in a following function.  I thought I had exactly 1340 frames in this render, but it turns out some got lost in some processing I did, so the code in the original question was 100% correct.  The segmentation fault was caused by a failure to read a file, ( I had forgot to pad zeros before the index of the frame).  Since the frame was empty, when I used a pointer to access data that did not exist I got a segmentation fault.